# sublime text 3 - change syntax colours

Tags: ubuntu, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I would like to change a particular syntax highlighting colour in Sublime Text 3 - how can I do that?

Most answers about Sublime Text concern Mac OS (some also windows) - any details (paths etc..) relevant to Ubuntu (or other linux distros) would be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the folder where sublime_text3 binary is.
Go to Packages folder
Open Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package
Find the concern color scheme. Open it in some editor and  change the values as per requirement. The archive manager will prompt for updation of file changes. Say yes.
Restart sublime 3.

Note: Sublime 3 Packages from this folder unlike sublime 2 which stores Packages in .config folder in home

Comment: It took me a moment to find, but it's in `/opt/sublime_text/Packages/`, at least on my Ubuntu 12.04. `Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package` has some non-text parts, so we'd best be careful our editor doesn't destroy those...

Comment: Can't believe we're modifying config files in the year 2014.... Linux illustrating why Windows so popular!

Comment: Most softwares need configuration. Most configurations need persistence. Most persistence is done in a disk file. Some sublime text configs are done exclusively by file modification. That's a sublime text behavior, there's nothing to do with Windows x Linux and most of the popular linux distros today provides screens and navigations to manage its configs. The Windows "ease of use" popularity is already in the past. Linux distros are as "ease of use" today and getting to the end user.

Comment: Comment to old post, I know, but still 1st hit for google search. This works in Windows IF you unzip "Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package", edit the scheme of interest (e.g., monokai.sublime-color-scheme), then zip -u "Color Scheme - Default.sublime-package".

Answer (score 2):

All the syntax colouring is done in your theme. All themes are located in `/Preferences/Color Scheme`

You can open the Preferences Folder by going to `Preferences` -> `Browse Packages`

Comment: Though if you are on ST3, they are actually being used from the `.sublime-package` files (which are renamed zip files). You can manually extract them or use [PackageResourceViewer](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer). Disclaimer - I'm the author of the plugin. I wrote it to make viewing/editing the built in files a little easier.

Comment: For ubuntu users who prefer command line to Nautilus, the folder is at `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`. Unfortunately, this location has nothing on syntax highlighting whatsoever, though it may be a place where overrides can be added??. `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Cache/` seems to contain something, but it's stored in some binary format, presumably the compressed format @suroda mentioned? May I ask what format they're in? My uncompressor wasn't able to shiff them...